# How do I force a Table to only show 1 row of data inside the cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

http://jsbin.com/ebiteh/3/edit

I would like that table to only show the first line of data, so for instance the cells should read: "hi","in","this is a really","another cell". I found a height of 24px was about appropriate here. How do I force the row of the table to only be 24px high?

Comment: Please post your code here so your question isn't dependent on people going to another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`overflow` doesn't work with `td`.  You can wrap the text within the `td` in a `div` and apply the height and `overflow` to the `div` instead.

Comment: eww this is disappointing, but you are correct it would work: http://jsbin.com/ebiteh/23/edit

Comment: also, you can use `em` for your height instead of `px` if you want it to be more dynamic based on your text size.  `1em` is the height of one line of text in your current font.